# Is there a way to automatically estimate the best degree of freedoms for a t-distribution using Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

A lot of the functions are simply asking for you to input the degree of freedoms to fit a distribution and return other items. However, I would like a function like R's fitdistr where it estimates the mean, scale parameter, and df. My ultimate goal is to obtain the t-score using that best estimated df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Scipy you can use the fit function associated with the t-distribution class to estimate the degrees of freedom, location and scale (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#fitting-distributions) and [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html) for more details). This estimates the parameters using maximum likelihood like the fitdistr function from MASS in R. E.G.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)

x = [ stats.t.rvs(9) for i in range(250)]
stats.t.fit(x)
```

This gives estimates of df = 5.63, location = 0.00 and scale = 0.85
A point of caution is that the estimated fit for the degrees of freedom  may not be great if you are also estimating scale and location. You may only hit a local optimum when you are maximising the likelihood function, so maybe standardise your data?

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on the local optimum problem?

And would scaling the data to zero mean be good enough to solve the issue?

Comment: Also, regarding your last statement. Are you saying the MLE is pretty good for df, but not so much for scale and location. Or are you saying it may hit a local optimum for all three parameters?

Comment: I just repeating the the caution given in the R documentation for fitdistr, really.  I meant it might hit a local optimum for all three parameters. Since you are just interested in calculating the t-score, I am not sure what's gained by estimating the location and scale (unless I have completely misunderstood your problem).

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering since I'm using ARCH to forecast the variance, I wanted to check how closely the fit() function predicts the scale and location compared to the ARCH. Right now it's far off, so I'm a tiny bit concerned. Although you're right, I only really need DF for the t-score.